# Extracting file extensions from file excluding query parameters SQL

Tags: sql, string, file, parsing, url

Is there a way to obtain only the file extension excluding query parameters using split_part and reverse from an SQL query?
ie.
`www.example.com?hffhqowhf`
or
`test.jpg?34rfqeyfhhf`

Returns:
com
jpg

Not tied down to com or jpg but in general?

Many Thanks

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: apache hadoop. not database per se but utilising sql style queries

Comment: Via impala......

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of achieving this (for example using a combination of INSTR and SUBSTR functions) but the cleanest way is probably to use a regular expression, something like this:

(

1. assumption: the string always has a query parameter starting with a '?' and that is the only occurrence of this character in the string
2. caveat: I don't currently have access to Impala so you may need to
   adjust the regex expression to get it to work precisely as you
   require

)

1. Reverse the string (REVERSE function) - so that the substring you want is between the '?' and the next '.'. If you don't reverse the string it is harder to identify which '.' in the string you are dealing with
2. Extract the substring between '?' and '.' but excluding these 2 characters e.g.

   select regexp_extract(reverse('www.example.com?hffhqowhf'),'?([^.]+)',1);
3. Reverse the output again to get the required result